# What is the need of readonly objects in c#? When shall we have our object as readonly in c#?

Tags: c#, object, readonly

I have an idea about fields being readonly or when shall fields can be readonly but I am not able to understand why objects can be readonly or when can we make our objects as readonly in C#.
Please help me understand this concept.

Comment: what's a "readonly object" in C#, for you ? I know about readonly fields, as you do as well, but I don't know a notion of "readonly object" named as such. Are you talking about immutability ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: Moved to answer

Comment: Are you able to show us an example of what you mean by a readonly object?

Comment: There are `readonly` fields, ie fields that cannot be modified after initialization. I guess your `readonly` object is referred to _immutable_ object, which (roughly) refers to object that does not change it's internal state. (think it as an object with all `readonly` fields or `get` only properties.)

Answer (score 0):

[Readonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) objects are initialized either as part of a declaration or constructor. Objects are made readonly for a variety reasons like preventing the initial values of an object from changing.

Comment: I feel like you describe a readonly field referencing an object. Not sure if this is what OP is talking about, though, because he explicitly dismissed readonly fields.

Answer (score 0):

Make it "readonly" through use of some magic to make the object immutable. So, you can have something like:

```
public interface IMyROClass
{
    string name { get; }
}

public class MyROClass : IMyROClass
{
    private string _name;
    public string name { get { return _name; } }
    public MyROClass(string name) { _name = name; }
}
public class MyClass
{ 
    private readonly MyROClass _myROClass; 
    public MyClass(MyROClass myROClass) { _myROClass = myROClass; } 
    public IMyROClass myROClass => _myROClass;
}
```

Comment: Your interface declaration is invalid. I'm sure that's meant to be a property, but as declared its a field which is invalid in an interface.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the sharp eyes. :)